# Add anchor to pdf using itext java

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, itext

I am trying to add anchor(named destinations) to pdf using itext java api. But it's not working.When I click the text , nothing happens.This is what I am doing .

```
 Anchor anchor =
            new Anchor("Jump down to next paragraph");
    anchor.setReference("#linkTarget");
    Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
    paragraph.add(anchor);
    document.add(paragraph);

    Anchor anchorTarget =
            new Anchor("This is the target of the link above");
    anchor.setName("linkTarget");
    Paragraph targetParagraph = new Paragraph();
    targetParagraph.setSpacingBefore(50);

    targetParagraph.add(anchorTarget);
    document.add(targetParagraph);
```

What am I doing wrong?. Any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked for me. `setLocalGoto()` and `setLocalDestination()` will do the magic.

```
Chunk chunk = new Chunk("Contact information");
    chunk.setLocalGoto("contact");  
    document.add(new Paragraph(chunk));
    document.newPage();
    
    chunk chunk1 = new Chunk("Contact information");
    chunk1.setLocalDestination("contact");
    Chapter chapter = new Chapter(new Paragraph(chunk1),1);    
    chapter.setNumberDepth(0);
    document.add(chapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing `anchorTarget` in `setName()`, that's why it's not leading you towards `#linktarget`

```
Anchor anchorTarget = new Anchor("This is the target of the link above");
        anchorTarget.setName("linkTarget");

        Paragraph anchorTargetLinkParagraph = new Paragraph();
        anchorTargetLinkParagraph.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        anchorTargetLinkParagraph.add(anchorTarget);
        document.add(anchorTargetLinkParagraph);
```