# How to Navigate from one page to another page in same PDF file using links in IText?

Tags: java, itext, pdf-generation

I have 2 PDF Files, One PDF File is created using Apache FOP and another PDF File is created by converting a word document. I need to merge both these PDF's into single PDF File using IText, which is already been done. In addition to that i need to create a link in my first PDF  which has to take me to the first page of the second PDF which has been merged.

The Problem here is i need to create the link from the first PDF by looking for a string/text like "Go To Page", if i find that string in my first PDF , i need to replace that string as a link , and on clicking on that link needs to take me to the desired page.

The below code actually does the page navigating job for me, but i'm not able to do that by creating a link as per my requirement.

Is it possible to find the rectangle coordinates of the string/text, so that i can pass those coordinates to create the link? Or Is there any way to replace my string as a link using itext?

I'm using IText 5.x

```
 public void pdfNavigation(String src, String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException 
{
  PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
  PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
  PdfDestination d1 = new PdfDestination(PdfDestination.FIT);
  Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 806, 595, 842);
  PdfAnnotation annotation1= PdfAnnotation.createLink(stamper.getWriter(), 
  rect, 
  PdfAnnotation.HIGHLIGHT_INVERT, 10, d1);
  stamper.addAnnotation(annotation1, 1);
  PdfDestination d2 = new PdfDestination(PdfDestination.FIT);
  PdfAnnotation annotation2= PdfAnnotation.createLink(stamper.getWriter(), 
  rect, 
  PdfAnnotation.HIGHLIGHT_PUSH, 1, d2);
  stamper.addAnnotation(annotation2, 4);
  stamper.close();
 }
```

Thanks for Help in advance !

Comment: First of all, you use a `PdfStamper` class, so I assume that you use iText 5.x (or below). Is that assumption correct? Furthermore, I assume that you already have a finished PDF document and have to add the link afterwards and cannot add the link during the initial document creation. Correct? In that case, is the text which you want to have clickable already in the existing PDF? Or are you expected to add it as part of your task?

Comment: Yes, I want it to make it as the part of the task, and yes i'm using i text 5.x

Comment: If you add the text as part of your task, you know where you are adding it. So where is the problem in determining the coordinates of the text?

Comment: @mkl sorry there was some confusion on my doubts, i have edited my question

Comment: Ok, I see that there still is a misunderstanding - links in a pdf are of the kind you found for your code: link annotations over some area. Thus, you don't *need to replace that string as a link*, you merely need to put a link annotation over it.

Comment: Yes, but later i noticed that the contents in the pdf are changing dynamically, so it is not definitive to put the link over some rectangle coordinates, instead is it possible to find the rectangle coordinates of a word/line so that i can pass that rectangle coordinates to the pdfannotation and will make it as a link. or is there any way to make that particular text as  a link which takes me to the desinbation page @mkl

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188860/discussion-between-pradeep-anand-and-mkl).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Chunk` class for this. I think you will get your answer from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50970199/itext-pdf-how-to-create-internal-links-to-other-sections-in-pdf?rq=1).

You can also use named actions for this like the below code which you can find in iTEXT documentation (Link is given below).

```
Paragraph p = new Paragraph()
    .add("Go to last page")
    .setAction(PdfAction.createNamed(PdfName.LastPage));
document.add(p);
p = new Paragraph()
    .add("Go to first page")
    .setAction(PdfAction.createNamed(PdfName.FirstPage));
document.add(p);
```

https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/books/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-6-creating-actions-destinations-and-bookmarks

https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/examples/itext-7/chapter-6-actions-destinations-bookmarks#2568-c06e02_namedaction.java

Comment: The OP uses iText 5.x (or lower). Thus, your answer likely won't help (unless the OP switches versions, that is).