# Link between different Sections in same PDF

Tags: java, itext, pdf-generation

We are creating a PDF document consisting of different sections generated separately and then added in single document. Now we need to provide a hyperlink to navigate the user to a point in different section.

We are using iText 7.0.5 and have tried using Link and Link Annotations, but no use. The mapping works for the same section but not between different sections.

Comment: I think the answer to the question [Add anchor to pdf using itext java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23423479/add-anchor-to-pdf-using-itext-java) could be helpful to you

Comment: Thanks. Tried that approach as well, but same result.

Comment: How do you create the final document? Do you have different pdfs which are then somehow meged into one document? Or do you create the conent of each section separately, but then add it one after another into the final document?

Comment: @UladzimirAsipchuk we create content of each section separately as byte array and then create PDFDocuments of each section, and then merge it one after another into the final document using PDFMerger (com.itextpdf.kernel.utils.PdfMerger).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your use case**: Merge pdfs and provide a mean of navigating in the resultant document.

**How to do it?**: Please look at the next iText sample: https://github.com/itext/i7js-examples/blob/develop/src/test/java/com/itextpdf/samples/sandbox/merge/MergeWithToc.java

In that sample some pdfs are merged and then a table of contents is created, so that one can click on its items and be navigated to the appropriate page.

In order to do so, it's suggested to set a named destination on some of elements of your "sections:

```
// Put the destination at the very first page of each merged document
if (i == 1) {
    text.setDestination("p" + pageNo);
}
doc.add(new Paragraph(text).setFixedPosition(pageNo, 549, 810, 40).setMargin(0).setMultipliedLeading(1));
```

and then to set an action on an appropriate TOC element:

```
p.setAction(PdfAction.createGoTo("p" + entry.getKey()));
```

Perhaphs the same logic can be applied in your case as well.

Comment: Uladzimir Asipchuk thanks for the solution. The above solution worked for our scenario, where we had to add one hyperlink to specific destination. But now we have a requirement where we require multiple hyperlinks, each pointing to different location/text. We tried to use same solution as above but every link is pointing to the last destination(eg. if we add 4 links, all links redirect to 4th destination only). 
Also, as per your solution the documents are pre-created and we are adding links to them while merging but in our case we are adding link while creating the documents.Please help.

Comment: As for the latter: there is no difference whether the document are pre-created or not. In both cases it's suggested to add an element with a set destination and then to refer to it from TOC.

As for the former: I've updated the code and everything is fine. I guess you create elements with the same destination set on it (in the context of the sample above, with the same setDestination()'s parameter.

That's how I have modified the sample above: https://pastebin.com/a1kZQ1sA

Comment: By the way, if you were satisfied with the answer, why didn't you neither accepted it nor upvoted? :)

Comment: Below is the URL for the question related to same issue/doubt posted by my colleague. Could you please go through the code and let us know what's wrong. Thanks.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55043420/how-add-multiple-links-in-same-pdf-using-itext

BTW, I accepted and upvoted the above answer :P

Comment: I ansered that question as well